# Is it safe to create a vector with new?

Tags: c++

When a vector becomes full it is reallocated and all of it iterators and pointers to elements are invalidated. Does this behaviour change in any way when the vector is created with `new`?

```
std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>(); //What happens if this vector gets reallocated?
```

And can I get the object from its pointer (as a separate variable), or do I have to copy it to another object?

Comment: The underlying array of the vector gets reallocated, the vector object itself does not move. The better question is, why are you newing a vector?

Comment: @Borgleader Because it can be done, so I'm studying it

Comment: @Borgleader Wait, why not `new` a vector? I guess if you're already using vectors you might just make a vector of vectors. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The semantics of an object don't generally depend on where and how the object is stored.

Comment: @Patrick87 Well if you need more than one yes I would suggest a vector of vectors over a newed array of them, but my general point was that the added indirection is unnecessary and a raw pointer means you have to remember to delete the object, all of this is extra works and sources of bugs that should be avoided.

Comment: Nothing changes with a dynamically allocated vector, except for the awkward syntax, the needless loss of performance, issues with life time management and issues with exception safety.

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as `v` is not destroyed, the *underlying* array (wrapped inside by the `std::vector` class template ) is in good state, irrespective of any reallocation.

Comment: So, basically, on reallocation the invalidation affects only pointer to elements and iterators? Not pointers to vector?

Comment: @RomanHudylko Naturally. Have you ever "lost" a `std::vector` non-dynamic object because it reallocated its internal storage?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the title question: yes, it's safe (if unusual) to allocate a `std::vector` object dynamically.

To answer the body question:

How the `std::vector` object itself is allocated does not affect the validity of its iterators etc. at all. They still become invalidated by reallocation of the `std::vector`'s internal data store.

For the final question, I don't quite understand. `*v` will give you a reference to the dynamically allocated vector. It does not copy anything. `(*v)[3]` will give you the `int` on index `3` in the vector, for example.

Comment: I was asking if I could get an object from a pointer, just like I get a pointer from an object. But I guess I can just copy the dereferenced pointer into a new object, right?

Comment: @RomanHudylko Dereferencing a pointer gives you a reference to the object. You can either access it directly, or copy it somewhere.

Comment: @Angew: To be clear, dereferencing a pointer does _not_ give you a reference to the object, if by "reference" you mean C++ References e.g. `T&`. But in the general English sense of the word, sure. :) I prefer "alias" or "handle" for that reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know it doesn't, but it gets fairly close to it. I don't think "it gives you an lvalue access to the object" is appropriate for the level of this question.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether you create the vector on the stack or on the heap. The vector actually owns the storage space which is probably just an array that it allocates and reallocates. The pointer you have is to the owner which doesn't change. The only difference with `new`ing it is that you are responsible for releasing the owner (presumably the owner releases the owned memory).

Answer (score 0):

Using new is safe, but doesn't help the problem you have with dynamic reallocation. The vector object promises continuity of the storage space, so there is not much you can do. After certain operations, you may not rely on iterators anymore. To prevent dynamic reallocation at unknown times use reserve() or resize() explicitly.